# Not able to do an API verification for the synapse homeserver

Tags: federated-identity, matrix-synapse

I have deployed a synapse homeserver with my domain. It's already setup and working but I have to do an API verification to check if all the API's are working correctly or not. I have gone through the official documentation but not able to figure how to use them in practical.
https://matrix-org.github.io/synapse/latest/usage/administration/admin_api/index.html

[image]

I am new to the industry so it would be better if somebody helps me with an example and the format to verify the API calls using curl while using the documentation.